Unable to use both route options and a nested resource callback in CakePHP 5.x
I'm trying to use nested restful routing by CakePHP 5, but it seems impossible to use both route options as an array, and nested resource definition as a callback. The following example does not work for nested routing, because it gets stuck with parsing the whole /id/nested-resource/id/ path.
$builder->resources(
            'Carts', [
            'id' => '[a-f0-9]{32}.*',
        ],
            function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
                $builder->resources('CartsItems', [
                    'id' => '[a-f0-9]{32}.*',
                ]);
            }
        );

I'm able to call Cart by custom ID, but CartsItems are stuck on Cart ID parsing:
GET http://{{host}}/api/carts/52de3c0b144e4ac9d2dae5ded023574b.json
results in:
{
    "cart": {
        "id": 4,
        "rid": "52de3c0b144e4ac9d2dae5ded023574b",
        "oid": "a4e3a4445311c9269e3648b7fc814f0e",
        "str_store_id": 2,
        "main": false,
}
}

GET
http://{{host}}/api/carts/52de3c0b144e4ac9d2dae5ded023574b/carts-items.json
results in:
{
    "cart": null
}

Another example:
GET http://{{host}}/api/carts/52de3c0b144e4ac9d2dae5ded023574b/carts-items/e7df9f1531ce7d4f3518defffd66cf1a.json
results in:
{
    "cart": null
}

The question is, how to use both options and a callback on the main route with sub-resource (nested route) definition?
